# Angular 7 Route animations not working in nested router-outlet

Tags: angular, angular-router, angular-animations, angular7

I'm currently experimenting with [Angular7 route transition animations](https://angular.io/guide/route-animations)  and have the following problem:

In my app there is a entry-component which has its own routing module and `<router-outlet>`.
What I'm trying to achieve is that whenever the route changes the old displayed component fades away (`opacity: 0`) before the new component fades in. But unfortunately I can't seem to make it work. 
The animations don't play at all, and debugging as explained in the angular docs:[Animations transition and triggers](https://angular.io/guide/transition-and-triggers)

```
(@routeAnimation.start)="onAnimationEvent($event)"
(@routeAnimation.done)="onAnimationEvent($event)"
```

shows that the animation is only triggered once (on pageload; and even then it doesn't play) but not while I use my navigator-component to navigate through the app.

My code looks like this:

**entry.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'entry',
  templateUrl: './entry.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./entry.component.css'],
  animations: [routeAnimation],
})
export class EntryComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() { }

  prepareRoute(outlet: RouterOutlet) {
    const animation = outlet.activatedRouteData['animation'] || {};
    return animation['value'] || 'WelcomePage';
  }
}
```

**entry.component.html**

```
<navigator>
</navigator>
<div [@routeAnimation]="prepareRoute(o)" id="entry-content">
  <router-outlet #o="outlet" name="entry"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

**entry-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'entry',
    component: EntryComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: '',
            component: WelcomeComponent,
            outlet: 'entry',
            data: { animation: 'WelcomePage' }
        },
        {
            path: 'introduction',
            component: IntroductionComponent,
            outlet: 'entry',
            data: { animation: 'IntroductionPage' }
        }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class EntryRoutingModule { }
```

**route.animation.ts**

```
export const routeAnimation = trigger(
  'routeAnimation', [
    transition('* => *', [
      group([
        query(':enter', style({ opacity: 0 })),
        query(':leave', [
          animate('0.5s', style({ opacity: 0 })),
          style({ display: 'none' })
        ], { optional: true }),
        query(':enter', [
          animate('2s',
          style({ opacity: 1 })),
          animateChild()
        ], { optional: true })
      ])
    ]),
  ]
);
```

Any Ideas what's missing/what I do wrong?
Help is greatly appreciated and many thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm struggling with the same problem.

Comment: I was facing the same issue and it ended up being caused by my prepareRoute() method.  I was checking activated route data for the animation (as in the Angular docs), however I was wanting transitions on all route changes, so I was not using route data to set the animation.  Needed to not check route data in my prepareRoute() method and everything is great again! :)

Answer (score 0):

Here, your

entry.component.html would be,

```
<navigator>
</navigator>
<div class="parent-router-cls" [@routeAnimation]="o.isActivated ? o.activatedRoute : ''" id="entry-content">
  <router-outlet #o="outlet" name="entry"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

entry.component.scss

```
.parent-router-cls{
    position: relative;
    router-outlet ~ * {
        position: absolute;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Here, I think you want animation on all router-outlet, I think don't need to add animation in entry-routing.module.ts

```
data: { animation: 'WelcomePage' }
```

So, your entry-routing.module.ts would be,

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'entry',
    component: EntryComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: '',
            component: WelcomeComponent,
            outlet: 'entry',
        },
        {
            path: 'introduction',
            component: IntroductionComponent,
            outlet: 'entry',
        }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class EntryRoutingModule { }
```

and animation file will be,

```
import {
    trigger,
    animate,
    transition,
    style,
    query,
    group
  } from '@angular/animations';
  
export const fadeAnimation = trigger('fadeAnimation', [
  transition('* => *', [
    query(
      ':enter',
      [style({ opacity: 0 })],
      { optional: true }
    ),
    query(
      ':leave',
      [style({ opacity: 1 }), animate('0.3s', style({ opacity: 0 }))],
      { optional: true }
    ),
    query(
      ':enter',
      [style({ opacity: 0 }), animate('0.3s', style({ opacity: 1 }))],
      { optional: true }
    )
  ])
]);
```